# WriteFile to an HID vendor Output report returns 1 because OutputReportByteLength is 0

Tags: winapi, hid, wdk

I am trying to get data into my microcontroller over i2c-hid from Windows. What I have is working if I hook up to a linux host (Raspberry PI). But on Windows 10, both WriteFile and HidD_SetOutputReport return 1 (ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION). I believe this is because the OutputReportByteLength in the CAPS structure returned by HidP_GetCaps is 0 (InputReportByteLength is also 0, same problem). The feature report I have in parallel to these input and output reports has the expected length, and I can get and set feature reports. Why does Windows incorrectly parse my report descriptor? Note that I have tried to rearrange the order of the feature, output, and input sections in my descriptor, and the feature report always works (977 for byte length in CAPS), and the input and output reports always return 0 for byte length in the CAPS structure.

### CreateFile

```
devHandle = CreateFile(currentInterface,
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
            NULL, // no SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure
            OPEN_EXISTING, // No special create flags
            0, // No special attributes
            NULL); // No template file
```

### WriteFile

```
UINT8 buf[9];
buf[0] = 0x9; // Report ID = 9
success = WriteFile(
        device->file,        // HANDLE hFile,
        buf,      // LPVOID lpBuffer,
        sizeof(buf),  // DWORD nNumberOfBytesToRead,
        &bytes_written,  // LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesRead,
        NULL         // LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
    );
```

### Report descriptor

```
//-------------------------------
// Decoded Application Collection
//-------------------------------

/*
06 00FF      (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0xFF00 Vendor-defined 
09 01        (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF000001 
A1 01        (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x00000001 Application (Usage=0xFF000001: Page=Vendor-defined, Usage=, Type=)
85 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_ID          0x01 (1) 
09 01          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF000001 <-- Warning: Undocumented usage
14             (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    (0)  
26 FF00        (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x00FF (255)  
75 08          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field

96 D003        (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x03D0 (976) Number of fields  
B1 02          (MAIN)   FEATURE            0x00000002 (976 fields x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
85 09          (GLOBAL) REPORT_ID          0x09 (9) 
09 01          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF000001 <-- Warning: Undocumented usage
95 08          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x08 (8) Number of fields  
91 02          (MAIN)   OUTPUT             0x00000002 (8 fields x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
09 01          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF000001 <-- Warning: Undocumented usage
95 40          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x40 (64) Number of fields  
81 02          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (64 fields x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
C0           (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Application 
*/
```

Comment: if you call `RtlGetLastNtStatus` instead `GetLastError` the result will be more informative, because several different status mapped to `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION`. however, faster of all original status is `STATUS_NOT_IMPLEMENTED` or `STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST`. this mean that write handler simply not implemented on device

Comment: I am implementing the device - the report descriptor I give I wrote and put into the firmware to be read by Windows. The device does implement a write handler - I wrote it, and it works on Linux. I tried `RtlGetLastNtStatus` and it returned `STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST` ... but I believe this is because Windows, for an unknown reason, determined OutputReportByteLength is zero. which is not what I put in the HID descriptor.

Comment: *The device does implement a write handler* - more exactly *driver* not implement `IRP_MJ_WRITE`. as result any write request to device return `STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST`. you **must** implement own `IRP_MJ_WRITE` handler or `FastIoWrite` if want another result.

Comment: We are using HID to avoid the need for a custom driver. Windows supports user-mode reading/writing to HID devices (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/sending-hid-reports-by-user-mode-applications) ... and again, reading/writing to the *feature report* in my report descriptor works fine. But I need to write to the Output (and read from the Input) reports.

Comment: anyway `WriteFile` is made call to some driver, and if driver not implement write handler - `STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST` will be returned. here need look - on which device you open file. to which driver it belong. device stack. need use devicetree for view

Comment: Looked at the device in device manager and clicked Driver Details: "HID-compliant touch pad: No driver files are required or have been loaded for this device." ... HID compliant devices are supposed to be able to be used from user-mode applications the way I linked earlier.

Comment: no, i mean [DeviceTree](https://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=97) utility. simply question - on which device your file (where you call `WriteFile`)

Comment: I'll post what DeviceTree showed, but again, the Windows HID layer is supposed to take WriteFile and add the appropriate headers and send it along to the bus. Even if the driver indicates it cannot support a write, that may be because it parsed the HID descriptor and decided that the writable length was zero. The device file is gotten from iterating over the devices from CM_Get_Device_Interface_List and using HID functions to get the device with our VID/PID and usagepage/usage. Here is a DeviceTree screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/wwNu1

Comment: (if you scroll in the imgur link, I include images of the leaf node and the driver node that includes the "Major Function Codes Supported" - IRP_MJ_WRITE is in there)